# Running newly created nativescript project build android error

Tags: webpack, nativescript

The error occurs when I build my newly created nativescript project:
`ns --version: 7.1.2`

Error:

> Preparing project...
> [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--env.externals=~/package.json'.
> [webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
> Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.

#### `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world",
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "version": "8.0.5",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "files": [
    "app",
    "App_Resources",
    "hooks",
    "tools",
    "!tools/assets",
    ".editorconfig",
    "jsconfig.json"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "nstudio",
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "beta"
  },
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

#### `webpack.config.js`

```js
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

Anyone have an idea about this error please?